# Application defined or object defined error on pasting value in a range

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Dim rOWIS As Integer

    Dim AOFF As Range   

    rOWIS = ActiveSheet.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A" & rOWIS).Copy

    AOFF = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rOWIS).Offset(1, 0)

    ActiveSheet.Range(AOFF).Paste
```

On 6th line i am getting an error 1004.can you please help me on this.

Comment: range object doesn't suppor `Paste` method. Use PasteSpecial instead

Comment: Perhaps it didn't copy over in your code, but it looks like you're also missing `Set` from your range assignment... You would need to write `Set AOFF = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rOWIS).Offset(1, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1004` is a `Object Defined Error` which resulted from `Range(AOFF)`.
Excel doesn't recognize such non-existent Range.
Dan pointed out a solution to propertly declare your variables using `Set`.
But what simoco pointed out is true as well, there is no `.Paste` method in `Range Object`.
so let's re-write your code to:

```
Dim rOWIS As Integer
Dim AOFF As Range   

With ActiveSheet
    rOWIS = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A" & rOWIS).Copy
    '~~> as what Dan commented
    Set AOFF = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rOWIS).Offset(1, 0)
    '~~> as simoco commented
    AOFF.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With
```

Above should work. I leave the testing to you.
Also refer to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) to avoid runtimes.

**Edit1:** Here is a shorter version of your code applying what's discussed in the link.

```
Dim AOFF As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set AOFF = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup)
    AOFF.Copy AOFF.Offset(1, 0)
End With
```